# How can I secure ELMAH for external access via the ELMAH-LogAnalyzer?

Tags: asp.net, security, elmah

I have ELMAH setup on an ASP.NET site and I would like to use the [elmah-loganalyzer](http://code.google.com/p/elmah-loganalyzer/) on it remotely, while still keeping ELMAH secure from prying eyes.  Basically, I want to be able to search the logs from home in an emergency without busting out the work-laptop and using the super-slow VPN.

I know I can secure ELMAH using forms authentication and/or IP addresses via the web.config as addressed elsewhere.  The problem is that the elmah-loganalyzer can't login with forms authentication (that I know of) and I would want to check it from a dynamic IP address, so those options are out.  The elmah-loganalyzer can login as a Windows user, but the website is not using that form of authentication.

Does anyone know of another way to secure ELMAH that the loganalyzer can use, or a way to secure just this one section of the site with Windows Authentication?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use it to connect directly to the database. Forms and Windows auth are used for protecting the web-based handler but the log analyser can connect directly to the DB (obviously with the appropriate credentials).

Comment: Well, I'm not currently using the DB option - its logging to XML files.  Switching to the DB may be my only work-around at the moment.  I might just have to fork and modify the loganalyzer at some point...